# One-dimensional array references to multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Why does this code compile?

```
int[] array = new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

On the left side is one-dimensional array. On the right I thougth that three-dimensional, but it is not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right side is a one dimensional array that is the first (0<sup>th</sup>) element of the two-dimensional array

```
new int[][]{{1}}
```

To show it out more clearly lets add parenthesis

```
int[] array = (new int[][]{{1}}) [0];// [0] is returning first row of 2D array
                          // which is 1D array so it can be assigned to `array`
```

Comment: `int[][]{{1}}` - I see two square brackets, so I suppose two-dimensional array. Why it is so? Could you explain more?

Comment: Now I understand. For those, who still do not see it: `int array = new int[]{1, 2, 4}   [0];`. First the array is created with three elements and I choose first element from this. It is only int.

Comment: @Pawel - Glad you figured it out. I was starting to write up an explanation when your second comment popped up. It's a good thing, too--I was not doing a good job of it. :)

Comment: @Pshemo - The edit makes perfect sense, although I'm not sure exactly what OP's blind spot was. The key thing to realize is that `new int[][]{{1}}` (with or without parentheses around it) is an [_array creation expression_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) and the trailing `[0]` is simply selecting the element at index 0 of the just-created array.

Answer (score 3):

The right side expression does two things.

```
//   instantiate new 2D array
//            ┌──────┸───────┑  ┌ access zeroth element of new 2D array
//            │              │  │
int[] array = new int[][]{{1}} [0];
```

This is basically equivalent to the following:

```
int[][] array2D = new int[1][1];
array2D[0][0] = 1;

int[] array = array2D[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional array is same as one dimensional array from memory management perspective ( meaning the data is stored in a single dimension). So, first element of two dimensional array is same as the first element of one dimensional array.

Comment: I know that multidimensional array is array of arrays in the memory. But `int[][] array = new int[5][10]` will pass, `int[] = new int[3][2]` will not. The sizes has to match, but in my example, in my opinion it does not.

Comment: I don't think size has to match because each element of 2 dimensional array is just a type of integer. so, i believe int[] array = new int[3][2] will work too.

Comment: Bu it doesn't. Try in compiler :p. Message: incompatible types.

Comment: You don't have to believe if you can just check it. And btw `int[] arrayX = new int[3][2];` will not compile because you are trying to pass two dimensional array of integers to one dimensional one.